# USB network card not detected at startup Ubuntu16.04

Tags: network-adapter, ubuntu-16.04, microsoft-surface

I have been using Ubuntu 16.04 on the surface GO since 2018.
To get wired network I am using a *USB-C 3 port USB + LAN adapter*.

**Problem**
Sometimes when starting up only the network card does not get detected but other devices on the Hub show up. This happens with three different brands of the similar kind of USB-C hub+Network adapter.

**Work-around**
Disconnect and reconnect the *USB-C 3 port USB + LAN adapter* the network gets detected.

**OS Version/Kernel**
Ubuntu 16.04 kernel 4.15.0-55 
Ubuntu 16.04 kernel 5.5.10-surface

Any reason why this occurs? Is it possible to reload any modules which will re-detect the entire hub or only the network adapter?

Answer (score 1):

from previous solution, I use this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $EUID != 0 ]; then
    sudo "$0" "$@"
    exit $?
fi

ids=$(find /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/ -maxdepth 1 -type l -exec sh -c 'basename {}' \; | grep ^0000)

for id in $ids
do
    echo -n "$id" | tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/unbind
done

sleep 3

for id in $ids
do
    echo -n "$id" | tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/bind
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using this script by
[Igdy Kajigger](https://disqus.com/by/igdykajigger/)

```
#!/bin/bash
id=$(basename $(find /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/ -maxdepth 1 -type l))
echo -n "$id" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/unbind
echo ''
sleep 3
lsusb
echo -n "$id" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/bind
echo ''
sleep 3
lsusb
```

From this link
[Reset USB 2.0 (ehci) & USB 3.0 (xhci) Without Reboot in Linux Kernel](https://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2016/06/reset-usb-20-ehci-usb-30-xhci-without-reboot-linux.html)